# How can you convert a GitHub action that uses Docker images into Azure Pipelines custom task

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a custom task to be published on the Azure Pipelines Marketplace so that people can use my security tool within Azure Pipelines. The task requires a lot of additional software, so Docker has been used for packaging.

I've similarly created the action for GitHub Actions, https://github.com/tonybaloney/pycharm-security/blob/master/action.yml

The action will-

- Use a custom Docker image (hosted on Docker Hub)
- Mount the code after checkout
- Run a custom entry point, passing the arguments provided to the action

I cannot see how to achieve the same thing in Azure Pipelines. All of the example code for custom tasks is written in TS/Node or PowerShell.
The only TS/Node.js [example](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/tree/master/node) doesn't show you how to do anything like download a docker image and run it.

The only other documentation I can find is about how to *build* a Docker image from within a Pipeline. But I want to download and run an image as a Task.

The [Task SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops) clearly shows how to construct the package,  but not how to do anything beyond getting it to pass arguments.

One possibility is to clone the [DockerV2 Task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DockerV2) and to customize it to run the Docker commands that I need, but this seems quite convoluted compared with how simple it is in GitHub Actions

Answer (score 1):

> How can you convert a GitHub action that uses Docker images into Azure Pipelines custom task

I am afraid you have to clone the `DockerV2` Task and to customize it to run the Docker commands that you need.

**The reason for its complexity is that their implementation forms are different.**

We are customizing github action and publishing to Marketplace, the custom github action did not compile and package the source code, but just quoted the original code. In other words, our custom action is more like providing a link to tell the compiler where to download the source code and pass parameters and rewrite the source code. So we don't need to download the source code of github action and customize it.

However, the Azure Pipelines custom task is different. The custom task needs to be compiled to generate a `.visx` file, which requires the source code and compiles it after rewriting.

Besides, Azure devops provide a [Task groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops), so that we could encapsulate a sequence of tasks, already defined in a build or a release pipeline, into a single reusable task that can be added to a build or release pipeline, just like any other task. You can choose to extract the parameters from the encapsulated tasks as configuration variables, and abstract the rest of the task information.

Hope this helps.